# Is there something in littigation for when a party isn't honestly trying to resolve the issue

Tags: canada, small-claims-court, litigation

I had taken my ex-landlord to court and am considering taking him again. He is a very dishonest person. Since court is a formal process, I don't know how to say this.

For example we reached a settlement which he didn't meat the deadline to. He explained he forgot to unblock my email address and is interesting in resolving this. But again he's just ignoring me. Also during a phone hearing the manager got confused and thought I was talking when in fact it was him (of course it's impossible for me to prove he's done this intentionally). When I try talking to him (in and out of court) he deflects questions, for example I asked why I hadn't got my damage deposit back and he responds "when will you be willing to address x, y ,z" where x,y,z are baseless accusations that  don't even have to do with damage deposit.

Can I sue him for "wasting time" like this? Is there some sort of abuse of process? Since he failed to comply with the settlement, can I get something in addition to the settlement being enforced, for example to compensate for the extra time it will take to enforce it? In a hearing he randomly said I stole something of his. Is this slander? (I didn't do it and he has virtually no reason to believe I did)

Answer (score 2):

You can't sue him for wasting time, but you can probably add interest for the delay. You can also use his previous agreements to pay you as further evidence of the debt, especially if you have them in writing (emails you sent him at the time *do* count for this).